# Is it necessary to use sample.split() function only on dependent factor?

Tags: r

Suppose we take the [sample data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0a9w.png) in this we have Purchased column as dependent factor. So if we need to perform sample.split(), it it necessary to perform sample.split on Purchased column itself??

```
library(caTools)

split = sample.split(dataset$Purchased, SplitRatio = 0.8)
```

or we can do any other column like

```
split = sample.split(dataset$Age, SplitRatio = 0.8)
```

or on the entire data set as a whole ?

```
split = sample.split(dataset, SplitRatio = 0.8)
```

Comment: Paste your data as text, read about reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: The function expects a vector, not a whole data.frame, so your last version may not be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks @RomanLuštrik what about taking any other vector other than dependent factor? why do we need to take dependent vector only ?